# How to check node.js code to code standards

Tags: node.js, code-standards

Does anybody know how to check nodejs code to code standards automatically? I'm looking for some features like codesniffer but for node.js (express framework).

Comment: https://standardjs.com/index.html#i-disagree-with-rule-x-can-you-change-it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) for node. Install it globally:

```
sudo npm install jshint -g
```

Basic usage:

```
jshint foo.js 
  foo.js: line 7, col 23, Missing semicolon.
```

You can create a custom configuration file named `.jshintrc` that contain [JSON JSHint options](http://jshint.com/docs/options/), and JSHint will pick them up. Example of a `.jshintrc` file:

```
{
    "strict": "true",
    "smarttabs": "true"
}
```

You can read more about how to configure JSHint on their [documentation page](http://jshint.com/docs/).

Comment: Can I add custom validation rules or create my own standart?

Comment: Yes, there is configuration information on the [docs](http://jshint.com/docs/) page for this.